# Kendo MVC Grid - filter empty values

Tags: model-view-controller, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to implement custom filtering to include/exclude empty values (filtering by one column)?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a new column (boolean) in your model to indicate that another column is empty. And filter on this new column.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a "not equal" filter on the desired column.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data:[{
          field1:"A",
          field2:"Z"
        }, {
          field1:"B",
          field2:"Y"
        }, {
          field1:"C",
          field2:""
        }, {
          field1:"D",
          field2:null
        }],
        filter: { field: "field2", operator: "neq", value: "" }
      },
      height: 550,
      columns: [{
        field: "field1",
        title: "Field 1"
      }, {
        field: "field2",
        title: "Field 2"
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/Esada

Comment: Thanks.. It works! How can I combine this filter with another one? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You just make it an array. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter

Comment: How to filter for the blank/empty values? Tried eq to '' but didnt work.

Comment: It should. There's probably another problem.

Answer (score 0):

---EDIT---
I did some research and i think ajax sometimes works with mvc ... anyways this is what you would do. I dont implicitly see the documentation for it or the mvc docs but its in the ajax docs
---EDIT---

If you set AutoPostBackOnFilter property of a column to True, the user does not need to press the filter button to initiate filtering. Instead, a postback filter operation occurs when the user types a filter in the filter box and presses [Enter] from the keyboard.

When AutoPostBackOnFilter is True, the column assumes a filter operation of Contains for string types or EqualTo for numeric types.You can change this to another filter function by setting the CurrentFilterFunction property. For example:

```
// filter out a certain column that is null
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName"
  UniqueName="ProductName" CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" />





/*
This is a rundown version of the above code
 if you happen to have a grid defined somewhere
 else in the code. Basically you would do this 
to apply the filter or  create multiple to apply 
multiple. 
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    filter: {
      ColumnName: "TheColumn",
      operator: "neq",
      value: ""
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: ill go ahead and add an edit to the comment !

Comment: I am still figuring it out but I think thats correct?